# MySQL Result Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Let's say I have this query in PHP.

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '1' ");
```

Which is nice and all, but I have a problem. How do I view the contents of $a, which I presume is an array like so:

```
Index          | Value
ID             | 1
Username       | Foo
Password       | Bar
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a)) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['password'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    echo $row['index'] . ' | ' . $row['ID'] . ' | ' . 
         $row['username'] . ' | ' . $row['password'];
}

mysql_free_result($a);
```

I prefere `mysql_fetch_assoc` to [`mysql_fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) since it's not appreciably slower, and it gives you the ability to call fields by name (e.g.-`$row['index']).

You could also use [`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) if you wanted the flexibility of referring to the row by index or by name. Really, just preference.

Answer (score 0):

see [fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)  [fetch_assoc](http://fr3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) [fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) for more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Or use :

```
var_dump($a, true);
```

if you just want to see the entrys..

Answer (score 0):

In PHP and its mysql functions, running `mysql_query()` returns an identifier that points to a result set. Therefore, you need [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or one of its brothers (`mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_object`, `mysql_fetch_row`) to actually pass the returned id to mysql to get a result set back.

I should also note that these functions just return a single row and advance the internal pointer to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with [mysql_fetch_row()](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_row)?  Combine with the list() language construct it works pretty well and offers strongly typed variable names.  I've used this several times:

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '1' ");

while(list($index,$id,$username,$password) = mysql_fetch_row($a))
{
    echo "Index | " . $index . "<br />"; // assuming this in HTML
    echo "ID    | " . $id . "<br />;
    echo "User  | " . $username . "<br />";
    echo "Pass  | " . $password . "<br />";
}
```